# Bluetooth headset stops working when mic used

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, microphone, a2dp

I'm getting some odd behaviour with my bluetooth headset and can't find any information about what is going on.  I have a Sony WH-1000XM4 and it is connecting fine with bluetooth, and I use it to listen to audio in A2DP mode.  I'm using ubuntu 21 with the included version of pulseaudio (14.2), which supports using the headset in either A2DP or HSP/HFP mode.  I prefer to use A2DP all the time and use a different microphone for making calls (from the camera).  In general this works ok, but then when I am in a video call (either gather.town or google meets), if I unmute the microphone and then start talking (only after I start making sound), there is a chime in the audio output (an upwards sounding chime) and then the audio output stops working.  The microphone continues working ok.  After some time (several minutes) there is a downwards chime and then the audio output works again.

I can't get any information about what is happening.  In the sound settings it still shows that output device (Headset WH-1000XM4) is active, and still shows it is in A2DP mode, so there is no clue about what it is doing.  I looked at the output with pulseaudio -vvvv but I can't tell what has caused this to happen.

I can use the headset in HSP/HFP mode to make a call and it works, ie it doesn't do the chime/silence thing when I unmute the mic and talk.  But the audio quality is poor so it'd be better to stay in A2DP mode.  I thought it might be doing an auto-switch and failing, but when I set `load-module module-bluetooth-policy auto_switch=0` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to disable switching it doesn't make any difference.  any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out what is causing this, and it has nothing to do with ubuntu/linux.  It turns out it is a "feature" of the headphones themselves.  There is a function called Speak-to-Chat in the headphones and it must have been automatically enabled when I installed an app for the headphones on my phone.

https://helpguide.sony.net/mdr/wh1000xm4/v1/en/contents/TP0002754732.html

So the way it works is it detects when you are speaking, and it turns the audio off to make it easier to chat with someone.  Unfortunately that doesn't work very well when you are trying to use the headphones for a video call.

So one solution is to use the app, find the switch for speak-to-chat and turn it off.  There is also a manual control in the above link, if you hold two fingers on the touch sensor panel it will disable(/enable) the speak-to-chat feature.